# Flex : dynamically created series doesnt show on the chart?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have the follow class :

```
package my.controls.charts.series
{
    import mx.charts.series.LineSeries;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.graphics.SolidColorStroke;

    import my.controls.charts.ICommonCharts;

    public class TimeLineSeries extends LineSeries implements ICommonCharts
    {
        [Bindable]
        protected  var dataProviderLineSeries : ArrayCollection;
        public     var rawData                : Array; 

        public function TimeLineSeries( seriesName : String )
        {
            super();
            this.displayName  = seriesName;
            this.yField       = "value";
            this.xField       = "dateBegin";

            this.sortOnXField = true;
            this.filterData   = true;           

            this.setStyle( "form", "segment" ); 

            var stroke : SolidColorStroke = new SolidColorStroke();
                stroke.color    = 0xFF0000;
                stroke.weight   = 1;
            this.setStyle( "lineStroke", stroke );

            rawData                = new Array();
            dataProviderLineSeries = new ArrayCollection();
            this.dataProvider      = dataProviderLineSeries;
        }

        public function Clear() : void
        {
            rawData = [];
            dataProviderLineSeries.removeAll();
        }

        public function ApplyData() : void
        {
            dataProviderLineSeries.removeAll();
            dataProviderLineSeries = new ArrayCollection( rawData );
            dataProviderLineSeries.refresh();

        }
    }
}
```

on the application i am trying the follow :

dinamicSeries : Array = new Array();
mySeries : TimeLineSeries = new TimeLineSeries( 'chronos' );
mySeries.rawData = randomData(); // it is a function which gain some random data
mySeries.ApplyData();
dinamicSeries.push( mySeries );
mainChart.series = dinamicSeries;

The new series name appear on the chart, but the data doest, and the chart always remains blank.
- What wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you affect a vertical axis to your newly created series ?

Comment: I have assigned, but seems it doesnt affect it. Is there a specific way to do it ?

Comment: Well, yes : mySeries.verticalAxis = myVerticalAxis;

Comment: You may find that this example helps http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/08/charting-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make public var rawData into a getter/setter pair, so you can populate the ArrayCollection with it.  So:

```
protected var _rawData:Array;

public function get rawData():Array {
    return _rawData;
}
public function set rawData(value:Array):void {
    if (value != _rawData) {
       _rawData = value;
       dataProviderLineSeries.source = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Amy. This way each time when i am adding element it will refresh the data. Something which is not desiarable. And this will not fix the missing drawing i think ... :|